# Get Branch Name from Workflow Run instance

Tags: git, yaml, action, github-actions

I have a yaml action running in GitHub that runs on the success of another action. The prior action runs with a variable for Branch Name which I get via:

```
echo "##[set-output name=branch;]$(echo ${GITHUB_REF#refs/heads/})"
```

When that job finishes this new one gets kicked off but it doesn't find the Branch Name in the same way as previous. It actually comes in as NULL which doesn't help my other scripts further down the line.

Is there a way to get Branch Name on a Workflow run?

Example:
Validate Pre Prod works only in a certain way on feature/* therefore I only want Deploy pre prod to do the same

```
on:
  # Triggers the workflow on push or pull request events but only for the main branch
  workflow_run:
    workflows: ["Validate Pre Prod"]
    types: [completed]

........

        #Find Branch Name and Outputs it as branch VARIABLE
        - name: Extract branch name
          shell: bash
          run: echo "##[set-output name=branch;]$(echo ${GITHUB_REF#refs/heads/})"
          id: extract_branch
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I would dump the `github` context and see what's in there: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#github-context

Comment: Your problem occurs because this workflow isn't trigger by a push or pr event, therefore there is no `github.ref` field filled in the Github context for its value (the same would occur for example trying to extract a branch from a trigger opening an issue). A workaround to resolve this could be to extract the branch name on the previous workflow and upload it as an artefact, and then download the artefact on this workflow to retrieve the value and manipulate it.